# The search from forceChatter:feed doesn't work

Tags: aura, customer-community, component

I created a aura component where I use forceChatter:feed.

My issue is related of the 'search' , the search doesn't work how I expected .

This is the error which I received when I try to use search : 'Sorry! We encountered an unexpected error. Please try reloading the page. If the error persists, contact customer support.'

I want to mention that I am in the sandbox and this component is added on the community page sites.

I don't have error in the log or in the console from browser.

Has anyone an idea or which is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code snippet so I can reproduce this behavior in my org. Thanks